# enable / disable options based on another select option

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a select box that enables/disable another select box options based on the selected value on the first select box.

The code below works well:

When I select **Junior**, the grade-level select options are disabled (**Grade 11 & 12**)

When I select **Senior** the grade-level selection options are disabled (**Grade 7, 8, 9 & 10**)

*Problem*

When I change back again to **Junior** or **Senior** all the options are being disabled

*Expectation*

When I change back to either **Junior** or **Senior** the options for them should be enabled.

```html
<select name="level" id="level" autofocus>
    <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
    <option value="Junior">Junior</option>
    <option value="Senior">Senior</option>
</select>

<select name="grade_level" class="grade_level">
    <option selected disabled>Choose Grade Level</option>
    <option value="Grade 7">Grade 7</option>
    <option value="Grade 8">Grade 8</option>
    <option value="Grade 9">Grade 9</option>
    <option value="Grade 10">Grade 10</option>
    <option value="Grade 11">Grade 11</option>
    <option value="Grade 12">Grade 12</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```js
document.getElementById('level').onchange = function () {
    var level = document.getElementById('level');

    if (level.value == 'Senior') {

        document.querySelectorAll('.grade_level').forEach(function(select) {
            Array.from(select.options).forEach(function(option) {
                console.log(option.value);
                if (option.value.includes('Grade 7') || option.value.includes('Grade 8')
                    || option.value.includes('Grade 9') || option.value.includes('Grade 10')
                ) {
                    select.removeChild(option);
                    select.appendChild(option);
                    option.setAttribute("disabled", true);
                }
            });
        });
    } else if (level.value == 'Junior') {

        document.querySelectorAll('.grade_level').forEach(function(select) {
            Array.from(select.options).forEach(function(option) {
                console.log(select.options);
                if (option.value.includes('Grade 11') || option.value.includes('Grade 12')) {
                    select.removeChild(option);
                    select.appendChild(option);
                    option.setAttribute("disabled", true);
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/thrivedigital/h4qo7n1c/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attribute and the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property... Your code could be a lot more concise.

```js
let gradeSelect = document.querySelector('.grade_level')
document.getElementById('level').onchange = function() {
  let level = this.value;

  gradeSelect.querySelectorAll('option[value]').forEach(function(option) {
    option.disabled = !(level === option.dataset.level)
  });
  // Sets the first one (Choose Grade Level) selected
  gradeSelect.querySelector('option').selected = true
};
```

```html
<select name="level" id="level" autofocus>
  <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
  <option value="Junior">Junior</option>
  <option value="Senior">Senior</option>
</select>

<select name="grade_level" class="grade_level">
  <option selected disabled>Choose Grade Level</option>
  <option value="Grade 7" data-level="Junior">Grade 7</option>
  <option value="Grade 8" data-level="Junior">Grade 8</option>
  <option value="Grade 9" data-level="Junior">Grade 9</option>
  <option value="Grade 10" data-level="Junior">Grade 10</option>
  <option value="Grade 11" data-level="Senior">Grade 11</option>
  <option value="Grade 12" data-level="Senior">Grade 12</option>
</select>
```

**Option**

If you want to have the enabled options on top, you can use [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append). It *moves* an already in DOM element.

```js
let gradeSelect = document.querySelector('.grade_level')
document.getElementById('level').onchange = function() {
  let level = this.value;

  gradeSelect.querySelectorAll('option[value]').forEach(function(option) {
    let match = level === option.dataset.level
    option.disabled = !match
    if(!match){
      option.closest("select").append(option)
    }
  });
  // Sets the first one (Choose Grade Level) selected
  gradeSelect.querySelector('option').selected = true
};
```

```html
<select name="level" id="level" autofocus>
  <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
  <option value="Junior">Junior</option>
  <option value="Senior">Senior</option>
</select>

<select name="grade_level" class="grade_level">
  <option selected disabled>Choose Grade Level</option>
  <option value="Grade 7" data-level="Junior">Grade 7</option>
  <option value="Grade 8" data-level="Junior">Grade 8</option>
  <option value="Grade 9" data-level="Junior">Grade 9</option>
  <option value="Grade 10" data-level="Junior">Grade 10</option>
  <option value="Grade 11" data-level="Senior">Grade 11</option>
  <option value="Grade 12" data-level="Senior">Grade 12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer this is very simplified, I'll use this instead of my original code.

Comment: Yes... More concise and more efficient too. Every times you can avoid a loop, do it! ;) Happy coding!

Comment: My code has `select.removeChild(option);` and `select.appendChild(option);` that pushes the enabled options on top, can't do the same with your answer because the `select` does not exists.

Comment: Thank you, If I can only accept 2 answers.

Comment: Ho... Pushing the enabled option on top is not an issue... hold on, I will edit.

Comment: Thank you, also on from @NcXNaV I've added this `select.selectedIndex = 0;` to reset the state of the grade level @louys-patrice-bessette

Comment: I can't seem to make the reset state of the Grade level work, tried adding this `document.querySelectorAll('.grade_level').selectedIndex = 0;` inside onchange but no luck

Comment: On change of the `#level`, you wish to *reset* `.grade_level` ?

Comment: Yes, I want to reset that

Comment: It's done..... ;)

Comment: The selection for grade level is now resetting when I change Level, thank you very much @ Louys Patrice Bessette, you've helped me until the smallest detail.

Comment: if you can help I'm facing another issue. The question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71650149/disable-select-options-based-on-another-select-option-after-page-load/71654860).

Answer (score 2):

You're disabling the options, but you don't enable it back to do the opposite so after both Junior and Senior are selected, all the Grades options are disabled.

Edit:
To select the first option, you just need to set property `selectedIndex = 0`

```js
document.getElementById('level').onchange = function () {
    var level = document.getElementById('level');

    if (level.value == 'Senior') {
        document.querySelectorAll('.grade_level').forEach(function(select) {
            select.selectedIndex = 0;
            Array.from(select.options).forEach(function(option) {
                console.log(option.value);
                if (option.value.includes('Grade 7') || option.value.includes('Grade 8')
                    || option.value.includes('Grade 9') || option.value.includes('Grade 10')
                ) {
                    option.setAttribute("disabled", true);
                }
                else{
                  option.removeAttribute("disabled");
                }
            });
        });
    } else if (level.value == 'Junior') {
        document.querySelectorAll('.grade_level').forEach(function(select) {
            select.selectedIndex = 0;
            Array.from(select.options).forEach(function(option) {
                console.log(select.options);
                if (option.value.includes('Grade 11') || option.value.includes('Grade 12')) {
                    option.setAttribute("disabled", true);
                }
                else{
                    option.removeAttribute("disabled");
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```

```html
<select name="level" id="level" autofocus>
    <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
    <option value="Junior">Junior</option>
    <option value="Senior">Senior</option>
</select>

<select name="grade_level" class="grade_level">
    <option selected disabled>Choose Grade Level</option>
    <option value="Grade 7">Grade 7</option>
    <option value="Grade 8">Grade 8</option>
    <option value="Grade 9">Grade 9</option>
    <option value="Grade 10">Grade 10</option>
    <option value="Grade 11">Grade 11</option>
    <option value="Grade 12">Grade 12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you very much! it's what I am expecting, also I see that you move the `select.removeChild(option);`, what's the difference of that?

Comment: One more thing @NcXNaV I see that the value remains selected after I change from Junior or Senior, how can you reset the state of the grade level when I choose again?

Edit:
I got it, I add this line `select.selectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: Your welcome! They are actually unnecessary. You don't need to remove/re-append the options, since you just need to enable & disable the options

Comment: Yes you are right. You can use `selectedIndex` property and select **grade_level** `default option` on value change.

Comment: is it okay if I accept Louys's answer?