# Disable select options based on another select option after page load

Tags: javascript

I've recently asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71543988/enable-disable-options-based-on-another-select-option), it's working fine as I expected **until** I found out that when I submitted the form and there's an error with the inputs (I'm using Laravel) after the page reloads the `Grade Levels` options which should be disabled some option based on the value of the `Level` selection options are now all enabled.

The expected outcome is even if the page reloads (*because of the error after the form has been submitted*) the `Grade Levels` options are still disabled based on the value of `Level`.

The value of the `Level` select box is preserved and selected after the error occurred, also did a `console.log` and it's showing the preserved value.

My approach is to have a `DOMContentLoaded` and place the JavaScript code there to handle the disabling of options based on the selected value in `Level` select option but I didn't make it work.

Code I'm trying to

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    let level = document.getElementById('level')
    let grade_level = document.getElementById('grade_level')
    let gradeSelect = document.querySelector('.grade_level')
    let currentLevel = level.value;

    console.log(currentLevel) // this shows the current value of level select option

    grade_level.disabled = true

    if (level.value == 'Senior') {
        grade_level.removeAttribute('disabled')
    } else if (level.value == 'Junior') {
        grade_level.removeAttribute('disabled')
    }

    gradeSelect.querySelectorAll('option[value]').forEach(function(option) {
        let match = currentLevel === option.dataset.level
        option.disabled = !match
        
        if(! match){
            option.closest("select").append(option)
        }
    });
});
```

Code which is working fine with all inputs in the form is valid (no errors and not being redirected back to the page):

```js
let gradeSelect = document.querySelector('.grade_level')

document.getElementById('level').onchange = function() {
    let level = this.value;

    gradeSelect.querySelectorAll('option[value]').forEach(function(option) {
        let match = level === option.dataset.level
        option.disabled = !match

        if(!match){
            option.closest("select").append(option)
        }
    });

    // Sets the first one (Choose Grade Level) selected
    gradeSelect.querySelector('option').selected = true
};
```

```html
<select name="level" id="level" autofocus>
    <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
    <option value="Junior">Junior</option>
    <option value="Senior">Senior</option>
</select>

<select name="grade_level" class="grade_level">
    <option selected disabled>Choose Grade Level</option>
    <option value="Grade 7" data-level="Junior">Grade 7</option>
    <option value="Grade 8" data-level="Junior">Grade 8</option>
    <option value="Grade 9" data-level="Junior">Grade 9</option>
    <option value="Grade 10" data-level="Junior">Grade 10</option>
    <option value="Grade 11" data-level="Senior">Grade 11</option>
    <option value="Grade 12" data-level="Senior">Grade 12</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

I've implemented Stephen and Louys's answer but none of them works in disabling the `Grade Levels` select options based on the preserved value of the `Level` select option after page reloads.

To explain what I mean in *page reloads* I have a form (post method) that is submitted and by using PHP Laravel as the backend I validate the inputs if there's an error with the inputs the page then reloads and I'm showing the error and also I'm able to get the previously selected value of the `Level` select box.

I have the previous value of the `Level` select box (it is already selected) and by that value I want to also preserve the current state of `Grade Levels` options - only enable what is connected to the current value of `Level` select and disable the remaining options.

Question:

Why do you need to show all the `Grade Levels` options again instead of also preserving the previously selected value?

A:

I want to do that but I can't because I'm also populating the `Grade Levels` options using javascript inside `$function()`

```
$(function() {
    // init the grade level options
    $('#grade_level').site_data('fetch_list')
});
```

My current code

```js
function updateSelect() {
  const level = levelSelect.value;
  
  // Ensure everything is enabled when no level selected (on first page load)
  if (level === 'Choose') {
    gradeSelect.querySelectorAll('option[value]')
               .forEach(o => o.disabled = false);
  }

  gradeSelect.querySelectorAll('option[value]')
             .forEach(function(option) {
    option.disabled = !(level === option.dataset.level)
  });
  // Sets the first one (Choose Grade Level) selected
  gradeSelect.querySelector('option').selected = true;
}

let levelSelect = document.getElementById('level');
let gradeSelect = document.querySelector('.grade_level');

// Update the selection when the page loads, so if 'level' already has
// a value the grade_levels will be enabled/disabled appropriately.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateSelect);

levelSelect.onchange = updateSelect;

let test = document.querySelector("#level")
test.addEventListener("change", function(){
    updateSelect()
})

let customEvent  = document.createEvent("event");
customEvent.initEvent('change', true, true);
test.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
```

```html
<select name="level" id="level" autofocus>
    <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
    <option value="Junior">Junior</option>
    <option value="Senior">Senior</option>
</select>

<select name="grade_level" class="grade_level">
    <option selected disabled>Choose Grade Level</option>
    <option value="Grade 7" data-level="Junior">Grade 7</option>
    <option value="Grade 8" data-level="Junior">Grade 8</option>
    <option value="Grade 9" data-level="Junior">Grade 9</option>
    <option value="Grade 10" data-level="Junior">Grade 10</option>
    <option value="Grade 11" data-level="Senior">Grade 11</option>
    <option value="Grade 12" data-level="Senior">Grade 12</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT #2**

Here, I will make `Senior` as default and we will try to see if the `Grade Levels` options will disable Grade 7-10.

```js
function updateSelect() {
  const level = levelSelect.value;
  
  // Ensure everything is enabled when no level selected (on first page load)
  if (level === 'Choose') {
    gradeSelect.querySelectorAll('option[value]')
               .forEach(o => o.disabled = false);
  }

  gradeSelect.querySelectorAll('option[value]')
             .forEach(function(option) {
    option.disabled = !(level === option.dataset.level)
  });
  // Sets the first one (Choose Grade Level) selected
  gradeSelect.querySelector('option').selected = true;
}

let levelSelect = document.getElementById('level');
let gradeSelect = document.querySelector('.grade_level');

// Update the selection when the page loads, so if 'level' already has
// a value the grade_levels will be enabled/disabled appropriately.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateSelect);

levelSelect.onchange = updateSelect;

let test = document.querySelector("#level")
test.addEventListener("change", function(){
    updateSelect()
})

let customEvent  = document.createEvent("event");
customEvent.initEvent('change', true, true);
test.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
```

```html
<select name="level" id="level" autofocus>
    <option disabled>Choose</option>
    <option value="Junior" selected >Junior</option>
    <option value="Senior">Senior</option>
</select>

<select name="grade_level" class="grade_level">
    <option selected disabled>Choose Grade Level</option>
    <option value="Grade 7" data-level="Junior">Grade 7</option>
    <option value="Grade 8" data-level="Junior">Grade 8</option>
    <option value="Grade 9" data-level="Junior">Grade 9</option>
    <option value="Grade 10" data-level="Junior">Grade 10</option>
    <option value="Grade 11" data-level="Senior">Grade 11</option>
    <option value="Grade 12" data-level="Senior">Grade 12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In your other question, where it uses an anonymous function `.onchange = function()` — you will want to take that and make it a named function so it becomes, for example if you called that function "updateSelect", `.onchange = updateSelect` — then you will want to run that function when the page _loads_, not just onchange, with something like `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateSelect);` This assumes that, as you say, when the page reloads after your submit the value of the level select box is preserved and selected.

Comment: Thank you @StephenP I'm getting the idea but got this error when trying to make it name function. `document.getElementById('level').onchange = updateSelect { }`

Comment: Where is the ajax you talked about in comments under Stephen's answer?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean in my ajax is the populating on the page loaded of Grade Levels options.. as I mentioned here "I want to do that but I can't because I'm also populating the Grade Levels options using javascript inside $function()"

on a fresh page, the options of `Grade Levels` are coming from the database and I used JavaScript to populate those records to the options of `Grade Select`

Comment: I don't see any ajax in your updated question — if you are using `<form method="post"...>` to submit and, when rejected, doing a full page reload then reacting to 'DOMContentLoaded' should work **IF** you are setting the `selected` attribute on Junior or Senior (whichever was selected when the form was submitted). If on page reload "Choose" once again is selected this won't work. It also matters what order the javascript is executed — if you are "populating the Grade Levels options using javascript" that has to be done **before** `updateSelect` is called.

Comment: @StephenP I didn't include the ajax part to populate/append `Grade Levels` options, and yes I placed the ajax part before the `updateSelect` but I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: @StephenP I've updated my question and added another demo for pre-selected `Level` this works fine here, maybe I'm having an issue where in I'm populating the `Grade Levels` options.

Comment: If you are getting updates from AJAX then it's invoked after a submit event. There are ways to bypass the reload and still submit to server. If the `site_data()` must be invoked in order to validate the inputs, then maybe invoking `updateSelect()` on a Promise chain with `.site_data()` would work.

Comment: @zer00ne thank you, but I gave up I can't make it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71543988/17300), where it uses an anonymous function `.onchange = function()` — you will want to take that and make it a named function so it becomes (for example if you called that function "updateSelect") `.onchange = updateSelect`

Then you will want to run that function when the page loads, not just onchange, with something like `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateSelect);`

This assumes that, as you say, when the page reloads after your submit the value of the level select box is preserved and selected.

Adapting Louys Patrice Bessette's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71544193/17300), I've pulled the function out to the top, set it up to be called when the page (DOM) is ready, and set it to be called onchange of the Level selection.

```js
function updateSelect() {
  const level = levelSelect.value;
  
  // Ensure everything is enabled when no level selected (on first page load)
  if (level === 'Select') {
    gradeSelect.querySelectorAll('option[value]')
               .forEach(o => o.disabled = false);
  }

  gradeSelect.querySelectorAll('option[value]')
             .forEach(function(option) {
    option.disabled = !(level === option.dataset.level)
  });
  // Sets the first one (Choose Grade Level) selected
  gradeSelect.querySelector('option').selected = true;
}

let levelSelect = document.getElementById('level');
let gradeSelect = document.querySelector('.grade_level');

// Update the selection when the page loads, so if 'level' already has
// a value the grade_levels will be enabled/disabled appropriately.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateSelect);

levelSelect.onchange = updateSelect;
```

```html
<select name="level" id="level" autofocus>
  <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
  <option value="Junior">Junior</option>
  <option value="Senior">Senior</option>
</select>

<select name="grade_level" class="grade_level">
  <option selected disabled>Choose Grade Level</option>
  <option value="Grade 7" data-level="Junior">Grade 7</option>
  <option value="Grade 8" data-level="Junior">Grade 8</option>
  <option value="Grade 9" data-level="Junior">Grade 9</option>
  <option value="Grade 10" data-level="Junior">Grade 10</option>
  <option value="Grade 11" data-level="Senior">Grade 11</option>
  <option value="Grade 12" data-level="Senior">Grade 12</option>
</select>
```

##### EDIT

When you are populating the `grade_level` as you show in the update to your question:

```
$(function() {
    // init the grade level options
    $('#grade_level').site_data('fetch_list')
});
```

This is likely happening *after* the DOMContentLoaded event fires and `updateSelect` is run, therefore there are no `<option>` elements in grade_level yet for updateSelect to act upon.

You should be able to solve this by doing all of your initialization in one place, either moving the call to updateSelect into that function instead of using the DOMContentLoaded handler:

```
$(function() {
    // init the grade level options
    $('#grade_level').site_data('fetch_list');
    updateSelect();
});
```

-or- eliminate that function and move populating the list into the DOMContentLoaded handler:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    $('#grade_level').site_data('fetch_list');
    updateSelect();
});
```

(note I have not tested these updated code fragments)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried it works fine but after page reloads, the grade level is still not selected

Comment: I mean, e.g. after the page reloads, the preserved value of `Level` select is `Senior`, the `Grade Levels` options are all enabled, instead of only enabling Grade 11 and 12.

Comment: Is that happening because I'm also populating the `Grade Levels` options via **Ajax** on `$(function() {  // here })` before the logic of disabling/enabling those options?

Comment: The `change` event fires only for a user change... not for a programatical change. So if `#level` value is changed in an ajax callback like `$(#level).val("Senior")`, just add `.trigger("change")` to it.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks, Do you mean instead of using vanilla js, I will need to use jQuery? sorry, I didn't quite get it, I'm naive in javascript and only rely on Google/StackOverflow I don't have the proper knowledge.

Comment: I write this `$('#level').val("VALUE-HERE").trigger('change')` the `VALUE-HERE` is now dynamic, how can I disable the `Grade Levels` options from there?

Comment: lol! No need for jQuery. The same can be done in plain JS. Here is an example in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1111). Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thank you! I'll check it now, I'm sorry the codepen is empty.

Comment: Woops... I forgot to save it lol! Here is the correct [link](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/bGaRLXN?editors=1111)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thank you, I've tried it, I still can't make it work.
```test.addEventListener("change", function(){
        updateSelect()
    })
```

Comment: You will edit your question showing the code where you at in the moment, including the ajax part.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I've updated my question and explained more about it. Thank you

Comment: Is `$('#grade_level').site_data('fetch_list')` Larvael? I've never seen a method name like `.site_data()` before...googled and zilch...

Comment: @zer00ne no, it's a function inside a `.js` file, inside that file is calling an endpoint.

Comment: @StephenP I'm sure your updated answer will work, I really don't know on my setup why it's not working, anyway will mark your answer as correct. Thank you! I see on my page that the `Grade Levels` options are showing delayed after a reload, but I tried both of your updated answer and call this line first `$('#grade_level').site_data('fetch_list');`